# How to extend PDO class with a new method and use that method in another class?

Tags: php, class

I once used to have my database connection in a file and included it on the pages that I needed it. Inside of this file, I also extended the PDO class with a new method, `run()`, which allows me to write shorthand PDO queries and worked fine:

```
class MyPDO extends PDO {
    public function run($sql, $bind = NULL) {
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($bind);
        return $stmt;
    }
}

$conn = new MyPDO("mysql:charset=utf8;host=$host;dbname=$name", $user, $pass);
```

I'm now trying to neaten up my files and the code within them, by using classes. So, this database connection file became two classes:

```
class MyPDO extends PDO {

    public function run($sql, $bind = NULL) {
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($bind);
        return $stmt;
    }

}

class Connection {

    private $_config = NULL;
    public $conn = NULL;
    public $error = NULL;

    public function __construct(array $config) {
        $this->_config = $config;
        $this->getPDOConnection();
    }

    private function getPDOConnection() {
        if ($this->conn == NULL) {
            $this->conn = new MyPDO("mysql:charset=utf8; host=".$this->_config['host']."; dbname=".$this->_config['name']."", $this->_config['user'], $this->_config['pass']);
            [...]
        }
    }

    [...]
}
```

At this point in time, I'm not using an autoload function to load the classes. There are only two classes needed for this particular file, so I'm requiring them manually. I'm also led to believe that including the connection class manually, allows the PDO class to be extended with MyPDO.

```
require API_ROOT . 'core/database/connection.class.php';
require API_ROOT . 'core/users/user.class.php';
```

I've tested the connection and it has indeed connected.

The problem I'm having, is using the new `MyPDO` method named `run()` inside of another class, in this case `user.class`.

Inside of user.class, I'm simply trying to authenticate a user and therefore need to use the `run()` method.

I call the user class like this:

```
$db = new Connection($config['database']);
$user = new User($db, $config);
```

And inside of the user.class, I want to use `run()` and do so by calling `$this->db->run`:

```
class User {

    private $db = NULL;
    private $config = NULL;

    public function __construct($db = NULL, $config = NULL) {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function login($email = '', $password = '', $remember_me = '') {
        $user_profile = $this->db->run("     <--------------
            [...]
        ", [$email])->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

}
```

But I receive the following error when I run this:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Connection::run()

I understand what the error means, that there is no method called `run()` inside of my connection class but why does it think that method is in there? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `$db`, which becomes `$this->db` in `User`, is a `Connection`, so `$this->db->run()` is trying to call `Connection->run()`.

Comment: `$this->db->conn->run` should work if you have the `db` as `Connection` class. Use type hints and an IDE understanding those. - Netbeans, PhpStorm, ...

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone - I have just tried `$this->db->conn->run(...)` and still get the same error.

Comment: @Nick, thanks but I have just tried `class Connection extends MyPDO` and `class Connection extends PDO` and have same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Quasimodo'sclone is correct, you need to fetch it from the `conn` variable as they demonstrated. If it's not working, you are doing something wrong on the implementation elsewhere because `run()` is a method of `conn` because `conn` is the class `MyPDO` which defines the `run()` method:

`$this->db` equals class `Connection` which creates instance of `MyPDO` in the `__construct()` and assigns it to `$this->conn` in the `getPDOConnection()` method – therefore `$this->db->conn->run()` is what you are looking for.

Your `getPDOConnection()` should maybe be renamed to `setPDOConnection()` then have the `getPDOConnection()` retrieve `$this->conn`:

```
public function getPDOConnection()
{
    return $this->conn;
}
```

Then your User class would actually use:

```
$this->db->getPDOConnection()->run(...etc);
```

It would make it a little clearer.